# Many to many tables combine in arrays

Tags: arrays, json, postgresql, aggregate-functions, jsonb

How can i SELECT book in this format:

```
{
   title: 'Avengers', 
   description:'Good book', 
   tags: [{id:1, name: 'Drama'},{id:2, name: 'Horror'}]
   authors: [{id:1, name: 'Alex'},{id:2, name: 'Tanya'}]
}
```

for tables with many-to-many relationships:

Or may be it's better to make 3 different pool.requests?

books

```
|id|title     |description|
|1 |'Avengers'|'Good book'|
|2 |'Fear'    |'Scary'
```

authors

```
|id|name
|1 |'Alex'
|2 |'Tanya'
```

authors_books

```
|book_id|author_id
|1      |1
|1      |2
|2      |1
```

tags

```
|id|name
|1 |'Drama'
|2 |'Horror'
```

tags_books

```
|book_id|tag_id
|1      |1
|1      |2
|2      |1
```

I used this before without authors table:

```
SELECT b.title, b.id, b.description,
 json_agg(json_build_object('id', t.id, 'name', t.name, 'description', 
 t.description, 'likes', tb.likes) ORDER BY tb.likes DESC) AS tags
 FROM books AS b
 INNER JOIN tags_books AS tb ON (b.id = tb.book_id)
 INNER JOIN tags AS t ON (tb.tag_id = t.id)
 WHERE b.id = $1
 GROUP BY b.id;`
```

But with new INNER JOIN for table autors there will be duplicate values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should aggregate the data (`authors` and `tags`) in separate derived tables (subqueries in the `FROM` clause):

```
select 
    b.title, 
    b.description,
    t.tags, 
    a.authors
from books as b
join (
    select 
        tb.book_id,
        json_agg(json_build_object('id', t.id, 'name', t.name) order by tb.likes desc) as tags
    from tags_books as tb
    join tags as t on tb.tag_id = t.id
    group by tb.book_id
    ) t on b.id = t.book_id
join (
    select 
        ab.book_id,
        json_agg(json_build_object('id', a.id, 'name', a.name) order by ab.author_id) as authors
    from authors_books as ab
    join authors as a on ab.author_id = a.id
    group by ab.book_id
    ) a on b.id = a.book_id

  title   | description |                             tags                              |                           authors                           
----------+-------------+---------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------
 Avengers | Good book   | [{"id" : 2, "name" : "Horror"}, {"id" : 1, "name" : "Drama"}] | [{"id" : 1, "name" : "Alex"}, {"id" : 2, "name" : "Tanya"}]
 Fear     | Scary       | [{"id" : 1, "name" : "Drama"}]                                | [{"id" : 1, "name" : "Alex"}]
(2 rows)
```

Comment: But do you think join with json_agg and json_build_object will be better that separate request?

Comment: The general rule is that aggregating data in derived table(s) before joining is faster (or at least not slower) than aggregating data on joined tables because the operation is performed on a smaller data set. Also, the single query (with derived tables) is a better solution than two separate ones (unless it is performed on extremely large tables).